Python Pytest Indirect Parametrization of Fixture with multiple Parameters
I have a question regarding indirect parametrization in combination with fixtures:
So in the official documentation and in all other examples I found, only one parameter was used in the fixture function.
Documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request):
    return request.param * 3


@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True)
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert len(fixt) == 3

So my question is: Does this work with multiple parameters?
Like so:
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def fixt(param1, param2):
    return param1*param2


@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", [(1,2)], indirect=True)
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert fixt == 2

When I try to do something like this in my project, I get an error message like fixture 'param1' not found.
If this does not work this way, is there any way that I can achieve to pass multiple arguments to the fixture via parametrization of the test itself?

So it seems that the parameter needs to be named request. And if you want to pass multiple parameters, one can access them with the param property. One side note: the type hint for request would be SubRequest
